# Why \begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft} doesn't behave as \flushleft...\endflushleft?

Tags: macros, environments, grouping

The following MWE points out that `\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}` doesn't behave as its macros counterpart: `\flushleft...\endflushleft`:

- `flushleft` environment's effect stops after `\end{flushleft}`
- `\flushleft` macro's effect continues after `\endflushleft`.

I wonder why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\section{Environments}
\begin{flushleft}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{flushleft}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Macros}
\flushleft%
\lipsum[1]
\endflushleft%
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all let's see `\endflushleft`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 3973:
\def\endflushleft{\endtrivlist}
```

Now `\endtrivlist`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 4425:
\def\endtrivlist{%
  \if@inlabel
    \leavevmode
    \global \@inlabelfalse
  \fi
  \if@newlist
    \@noitemerr
    \global \@newlistfalse
  \fi
  \ifhmode\unskip \par
  \else
    \@inmatherr{\end{\@currenvir}}%
  \fi
  \if@noparlist \else
    \ifdim\lastskip >\z@
      \@tempskipa\lastskip \vskip -\lastskip
      \advance\@tempskipa\parskip \advance\@tempskipa -\@outerparskip
      \vskip\@tempskipa
    \fi
    \@endparenv
  \fi
}
```

OK, nothing very strange. But the problem is in `\flushleft`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 3972:
\def\flushleft{\trivlist \raggedright\item\relax}
```

The `\raggedright` declaration is not surrounded by a group, so even upon finding `\endflushleft` it continues forever.

But `\end{flushleft}` also provides an `\endgroup` token, which will match the `\begingroup` issued by `\begin{flushleft}` (before doing `\raggedright`), so the `\raggedright` setting will be undone.

You are not supposed to use `\flushright` and `\endflushright` in a document. They can be used in definitions of environments, though.

Comment: Say that I am defining a new environment in which the text is going to be flushed left. Is it a good practice to use these macros or it is better to stick to `\begin{flushleft}` within my new environment? why/why not?

Comment: @Pouya `\newenvironment{myflushleft}{...\flushleft...}{...\endflushleft...}` (where `...` stands for other code) will give a better error message in case you forget `\end{myflushleft}`, saying that `myflushleft` was not finished. With `\begin{flushleft}` and `\end{flushleft}` in the definition, the error message would tell you that `flushleft` is unfinished.

Comment: I didn't know it was necessary to be speleologist in order to answer my question! ;) I didn't plan to use `\flushright` and `\endflushright` in a document but rather in (`LaTeX3`) class, each of them in private macros used several times. By the way, shouldn't `\raggedright` declaration be surrounded by a group?